# How to access contracts array property

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a contract like this:

```
contract Test
{
     uint256 public delay;
     uint256[] public timings;
}
```

Now I am interacting from web3.js with the contract like this

```
const contract = new Web3(window.ethereum).eth.Contract(ABI, address)
// works fine
const deley = await contract.methods.delay().call()
// fails with 'reverted' error
const deley = await contract.methods.timings(0).call()
```

And as you can see get 2 different results. When I am accessing a regular property the value is returned correctly, however when I am trying to access an array I am getting just the 'reverted' error:

```
{code: -32000, message: "execution reverted"}
```

Any idea how can I access the array from just simeple js frontend app ?

Mind you that the following construct works just fine when I execute it via truffle exec:

```
const contract = await Test.at(address);
const first = await contract.timings(0);
```

Which puzzles me even more!

Answer (score 0):

```
// fails with 'reverted' error
const deley = await contract.methods.timings(0).call()
```

`timings` in your snippet is an **empty** array, it doesn't have an item with index 0. So when your call from web3 is trying to access the (non-existing) index 0, it's an invalid call.

---

```
const contract = await Test.at(address);
const first = await contract.timings(0);
```

Truffle acts differently and for **calls** (not transactions) ignores the dynamic-sized array (or mapping) length. Then looks for the value in the storage an since the value is not set, it's always (almost always, there are some edge cases) 0.